# jQuery hero slider logic, not(:first) isn't working for me

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
    $('#btn-homeheroleft').click( function() {
    if ( $('#homehero-btns a.on:not(:first)')) {
        $('#homehero-btns a.on').prev('a').trigger('click');
    } else {
        //$('#homehero-btns a.on').prev('a').trigger('click');
        $('#homehero-btns a').last('a').trigger('click');
    }
    //return false;
});
```

It works fine to rotate the hero banner until it gets to the first one, in which it should return to the last looping around, however it never makes it to the else, and always evaluate true on the if for some reason.

I've executed `$('#homehero-btns a').last('a').trigger('click')` in the console and it works just fine there.

**UPDATE:**

Here was the solution to my issue if anyone is interested, thank you everyone for your help.

```
    $('#btn-homeheroleft').click( function(e) {
    if ( $('#homehero-btns a:first').hasClass('on') ) {
        $('#homehero-btns a:last').trigger('click');
    } else {
        $('#homehero-btns a.on').prev('a').trigger('click');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
    $('#btn-homeheroright').click( function(e) {
    if ($('#homehero-btns a:last').hasClass('on')) {
        $('#homehero-btns a:first').trigger('click');
    } else {
        $('#homehero-btns a.on').next('a').trigger('click');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
}
```

Comment: why wouldn't it always be true? you aren't changing anything you are using the same selector every time

Comment: can you post the html and any other relevant js?

Comment: there are 3 elements it cycles through, for each slide, so when it gets to :first, shouldn't it go to "else", as the if s asking if its not first? Maybe im confused. I just need it to click the last button element when its on the first one already (which adds teh "on" class, and vice versa when it gets to the end. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

As you asked about the hero slider logic, I will address the structure and method part, ignoring your current code (might work, but could be better.)

For the case, where the rotation have to unlimited. You can use a very simple trick. Each time you rotate it to the next image (or slide, with whatever content)..you want to move the last image to the front and vice versa.

I once made a very simple slider rotator to some question over here. This is a very good example on how easy it is to make the rotator dynamic: http://jsfiddle.net/PmXr2/1/ You can use that code however you want.

[image]

Comment: Hi There Kalle, thanks for your suggestions, very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try adding .length to ur selector

```
$('#btn-homeheroleft').click( function() {
    if ( $('#homehero-btns a.on:not(:first)').length) {
        $('#homehero-btns a.on').prev('a').trigger('click');
    } else {
        //$('#homehero-btns a.on').prev('a').trigger('click');
        $('#homehero-btns a').last('a').trigger('click');
    }
    //return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks a ton, but got this: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'length' of object [object Object] is not a function :(

Comment: so .length instead of .length()

Comment: Hi Evan, posted as an update what ended up working for me, thanks again for your help.